# Repeat background image horizontally on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, cross-browser

Site: http://bit.ly/1g0pm65

I have been debugging this site for iPad and can't seem to get the footer and header backgrounds to span full width. It looks fine on the web but for some reason iPad show sup like the attached images (not full width), thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a common issue that might be fixed by setting a min-width on the HTML element. See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12242229/2765713

Feels like a bit of a hack though, will need thorough testing cross browser/device.