# Background image on Ipad do not display 100%

Tags: ios, css, html, ipad

The image that I use for my background (which is fixed) displays at 100% in Web format, but when I emulate it on Ipad (1024x768), the image stops adapting to the width of the screen and it just fills about 70% of the screen height.

This is the CSS that I've used for the website format:

```
.body{
  background-image: url("/img/bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  height: 5700px;
  width: 100%;
    }
```

This is the CSS that I've used for the Ipad style:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
.body{
    background-image: url("/img/bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    height: 5700px;
    min-width: 1024px;
  }
}
```

I've tried `min-width: 1024px;` beacause I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388070/background-image-width-not-100-on-ipad) with that suggestion, but it hasn't worked.

Comment: can u try width: 100vw;? If it helps i will write an answer

Comment: @Traver ok, I'll try it now.

Comment: I've tried it on background-size (not on width) and it has worked! Thanks! I'll post the complete answer below.

Comment: i saw that you will use vh/vw units. check my answer below please for important information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated here [viewport units caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) , using viewport units can ( and will ) cause problems in iOS because

> iOS 7 Safari recalculates widths set in vh as vw, and heights set in vw as vh, when orientation changes.
>
> iOS 7 Safari sets viewport unit values to 0 if the page has been left and is returned to after 60 seconds.
>
> vh on iOS is reported to include the height of the bottom toolbar in the height calculation, and the width of the sidebar (bookmarks) in the vw width calculation.

So i suggest you use media queries and target different iOS resolution both for portrait and landscape. I know, it's a meticulous task but if you have a serious project for a serious customer , you have to deliver serious product

See here > [iosres](http://iosres.com/)

For example

```
 /* iPad with portrait orientation.*/
 @media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait){
   .body{
    height: 1024px;
   }
 }


  /*iPad with landscape orientation.*/
 @media all and (device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape){
   .body{
     height: 768px;
   }
 }

/*iPhone 5 with aspect ratio*/
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {
  .body {
    height: 500px;
  }
}
```

or you could use jQuery or javascript , for example

```
$(".body").height($(window).height())
```

this will equal body height to window height

Comment: Wow, thanks for the info. As I am developing the project with React.js I can't use jQuery, but I'll do your first option. I'll mark your answer as the best one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `width: 100vw`. vw means viewport width, so this should make the background take up the full width of the viewport.

Comment: Yup, I had to change my units. I've fully explained what I've done below. And thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Traver I've found the answer:

```
.body{
    background-image: url("/img/bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 200vh;
    height: 5700px;
    width: 100%;
  }
```

I just had to change the background-size units to vh and remove auto (but I've tested with it too and it's worked). Giving it a number of 200vh is enough to scale it full width and height.

EDIT: Mihai T's answer is the best one. Check it.